# How do I prepend a String to an Android TextView?

Tags: android, layout, textview

There's TextView.append(), but that adds the text to the end of the TextView. I want what I append to go in the beginning (ie, show up on the top of the TextView box).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
 textview.setText(" append string" + textView.getText());
```

Though the spannables will get lost by this method.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this seem very ugly to other people too? Is there a reason android doesn't include a prepend() or something similar?

Comment: i guess append is frequently used. So android provides append as a convenience function

Answer (score 9):

If you're concerned about spannables, you can use something like this:

```
textView.getEditableText().insert(0, "string to prepend");
```

Comment: I vote this for it is much faster  than setText(...) when the textView has big size text.

Answer (score 3):

The getEditableText() returned null to me. Instead, to prepend text to a spannable, I set the text buffertype to SPANNABLE:
in code:

```
myTextView.setText(myText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

or using xml property [android:bufferType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3abufferType) on your TextView.

Then cast the getText() to Spannable, after which I concat the extra text with existing text:

```
Spannable currentText = (Spannable) tvTitle.getText();
CharSequence indexedText = TextUtils.concat(String.format("%d. ", index), currentText);
myTextView.setText(indexedText);
```

As far as I can tell all functions are available from API level 1.

Comment: Of the multiple incorrect solutions I've found littered around for this, this is the only solution that actually works.

Absolutely insane that there is not a more sane way to do this.

Below my similar code taking advantage of this.

`code`
    setText(getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable currentText = (Spannable)getText();
    CharSequence indexedText = TextUtils.concat("(", currentText, ")");
    setText(indexedText);
`code`

Answer (score 2):

Then use the string you want to append say "hello" to the textview as

```
textview.setText("hello"+textView.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential quick prepend option:

```
val myPrependedText = "My prepended text: "
val myTextView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
"$myPrependedText${myTextView.text}".also{myTextView.text = it}
```